# Display data in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new in jsp and faced with one problem. I need to create jsp page, that displays data from servlet.
Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    CustomersDao customersDao = new CustomersDaoImpl();
    List<Customers> custList = customersDao.getAllCustomers();
    request.setAttribute("customersList", custList);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request, response);        
}
```

jsp page code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%-->
        <table border="1">           
            <tr>
                <td>${requestScope['customers'].name}</td> 
                <td>${requestScope['customers'].lastname}</td> 
                <td>${requestScope['customers'].totalAmount}</td>
            </tr>              
        </table>
        <--%>

        <table border="1">
            <c:forEach var="element" items="${requestScope['customersList']}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${element.name}" /> TEST.name</td> 
                    <td>${element.lastname} TEST.lastname</td> 
                    <td>${element.totalAmount} TEST.totalAmount</td>
                    <td> ololo </td>
                </tr> 
             </c:forEach>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I send single object to jsp it's work normally (commented part of code). But when I try to send list, I can not separate object and browser shows me only test messages. So how do I fix it?

Comment: try only ${customersList}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I send single object to jsp it's work normally (commented part of code). But when I try to send list, I can not separate object and browser shows me only test messages.

You have forgotten to include the core tag library. that's why `<c:forEach>` is not working but it works if you pass just single object.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```